# How to block a process with Windows Firewall?

Tags: system, block, pid

There is a System process (PID == 4) in windows. It uses more internet, how can I block this process from using the internet,

once I blocked with firewall inbound and outbound connections, it has worked for 5 days, after 5th day it uses the internet again.

Answer (score 0):

"System Process" represents the operating system (some system services) and the drivers.

Notably, **antiviruses** and malware tools use the "System Process". Blocking it indiscriminately is not a good practice as you can break core functionalities.

Inspect your configuration and the traffic in order to spot which "applcation" is consuming so much bandwidth.

Comment: want to block just connection with internet not its work offline on pc.

Comment: The matter is that "System Process" is an intermediary. If you reliably want to block something there, you should understand "who is asking to surf the web as a system process"? That way you clearly can stop the traffic at the source. If you really want to do something bad, just install a custom firewall and block the traffic there (or use an hardware firewall to do such job). If you take this route, you won't ever be sure you are blocking all the traffic, as you do not know who is the offender. Knowing the offender is, in my opinion, the only reliable way to approach the problem.